# flying insect the size of a bird

Tags: entomology

On my farm a few weeks ago I started to see a large insect(?) I never, in my 76 years, seen before.

It is bright yellow, about the size of a man's hand, flies not like a bird but more like a butterfly and its large long legs hang down in flight. Observations are from 75 yards away.

The encounters are too brief to get a picture or even a magnified view without stationing myself in position all day.

Comment: It could be a hornet, try to film it, maybe it's easier to recocnise it then.

Comment: Could be a bat or such?

Comment: There seems too little way to proceed with so little information. Man's hand mean entire hand from shoulder to fingers (near 3 feet or 1 meter)? or you meant palm (half feet or less)? please write in clear way. If you mean palm, then yes I saw palm-sized butterflies in many museum (such as *Papilio krishna*). When it comes out? Day? night? morning? dawn? Which place or locality or region it saw it?

Comment: @BunyanvanAsten Hornet of size of man's hand? you mean approx 1 meter long hornet?

Comment: The hand of a man; 6 or 7 inches. See them (4) morning and afternoon. The legs are long and hang down in flight. Wish I could get closer or maybe snap a picture. It's one of those things, like a movie, you wait for an hour, see none, then when you turn and walk away, they appear.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: Your *hands* are 1m long?

Comment: @Edwin: Please edit your question.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Oh god I told in approximate way. I was trying to understand about-whom the OP using the term 'hand'. I cant imagine a hornet of full-length of my 'hand'. Ok I'll measure my hands later plz wait...

Comment: @MartinSchröder Perhaps you're meaning 'palm' with your 6 or 7 inch.

Comment: plz Visit this. http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/are-there-any-guideline-about-species-identification-questions/3453#3453. It might help.

Comment: Without seeing it my guess would be a Hummingbird moth or Clearwing.. Look it up